# I have an outside light contolled by a switch. How do I add an always on power plug at the end of this circuit?

Tags: electrical

I have an outside light contolled by a switch. How do I add  an always on power plug at the end of this circuit?
This is a three wire cable
The extension will be used to power up a surveilance camera that requires two wires

Comment: If power goes to the switch first then light, probably difficult.  If power to light first, then easier.  By three wire cable you mean black,red and white or black and white plus ground?

Comment: black white and ground. The switch comes first, it is inside

Comment: Easiest way is to make the light itself switchable(smart, motion, pull cord), then add an outlet.  Remove switch or leave always on.

Comment: I can't because it is used for a patio area where I have a table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With only a 2 wire circuit the only way you could do something similar to what you want would be to make the circuit always hot and control the light with a "dusk to dawn" photo cell. Other than this you will need to run more wires.

Comment: Smart bulbs can also be a good option for an always hot light socket.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Your circuit will be controlled by the light switch. There's no good reason to run a parallel, but completely unused circuit.

You'll need to run a new wire before the switch to supply power, or rewire your existing switch's junction box to be always on and move the switch further down the line after you split the power to feed the cameras.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to identify a pair of "smart switch" and "smart light bulb" that can be made to talk to each other wirelessly or with powerline signaling.

At that point, you wire the circuit so black is always-hot everywhere, and white is neutral everywhere.

Install the switch.  Pair the smart bulb to the smart switch.

Profit!

Another option is to run a *low voltage* cable to the camera.  The camera doesn't need 120V, it needs 12V or 5V or some other low-risk DC voltage.  The rules for running low-voltage cables are relaxed compared to the rules for running AC power cables, so you can take more installation shortcuts.

Comment: It is the runnig of another cable that I am trying to avoid. Yes probaby smat things could solve the problem I wish I could pick your answer as the right one but so far it is just an assumption that this could be solved that way. I need to identify if there are such components and this also require adding more things to what is there. I was looking for a simple wiring and regular switches thing